# Download file from a website

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

I'm looking for help about my little program. I would like to download a setup (.exe) from a website using QNetwork class. I've already search and read many post about it, but it doesn't work.

download.cpp :

```
Download::Download(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
}

void Download::initialiseDownload()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request;

    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.mylink.com/setup.exe"));
    reply = manager.get(request);

    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(downloadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(updateProgress(qint64, qint64)));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(downloadFinished()));
}

void Download::downloadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{
    qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    reply->deleteLater();
}

void Download::updateProgress(qint64 read, qint64 total)
{
    qDebug() << "Progress...";
    qint64 percent = (read / total) * 100;
    qDebug() << percent;
}

void Download::downloadFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Finished !";
    QByteArray b = reply->readAll();
    QFile file("./sdk/setup.exe");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << b;
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

download.h :

```
#include "launcher.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork>

class Download : public QObject, public Launcher
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Download(QObject *parent = 0);
    void Download::initialiseDownload();

private slots:
    void downloadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err);
    void updateProgress(qint64 read, qint64 total);
    void downloadFinished();

private:
    QNetworkReply *reply;
};
```

I've added the dlls for OpenSSL and it work. I've also added "network" to the ".pro" file. But, when I run my program, and I click on the push button from another class, initialiseDownload() is working, but signals seem to be inactive.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

In your `Download::initialiseDownload()` function, you create a `QNetworkAccessManager` that goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Put your `QNetworkAccessManager` as a member variable or somewhere where it lives for at least the duration of the download.

Considering that you call your class "Download", it is probably most logical that the `QNetworkAccessManager` lives in ( or is ) the parent of your `Download` instance, since you ( can ) start multiple downloads simultanously with the same `QNetworkAccessManager`.